# Microsoft Office stopped working properly

Tags: microsoft-office, dll

I used the following link to include a new language and Word stopped working properly

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/enable-editing-of-multiple-languages-HP003084566.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP003089543

I am using Windows 7 and tried to return to a previous stage but the problem remained. I tried to uninstall and reinstall Office but got the following error message:

E : \Homestudent Fr. WWW\OSETUP.DLL digital signature does not validate or is not present.

Excel stopped working as well. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "stopped working"?

Comment: You may want to make the title of this question more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

There are some working solutions to this problem on [Microsoft Technet Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/dc31526b-efd3-420b-927a-5dc5de7a2bc6/). Have a look.